# Trying to store part of the urls in an array and then map it to a series of clicks

Tags: jquery

I am trying to store a part of the destination urls in an array and then pass the path of the parent url as an argument to the window.location function upon click. I am sure I am missing some solid piece in here.

This is what I have

```
<ul>
    <li class="trigger"></li>
    <li class="trigger"></li>
    <li class="trigger"></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
var arrayOne = ['/add', '/addBack', '/addClass'];


$('.trigger').click(function(){
    window.location('src', 'http://api.jquery.com/' + arrayOne[$('.trigger').index(this)])
});
```

Here is my fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/RADfb/6/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location is not a function !!!

if you want to redirect use windown.location.href instead.

```
window.location.href = 'http://api.jquery.com/' + arrayOne[$('.trigger').index(this)]
```

Comment: @soum you're welcome, don't forget to mark the question as resolved ;)